# Object containing array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to construct an object, where one of the property is going to be an array:

```
var a = 1;
var b = ["a","b"]
var b1 = ["c","d"]
var c = {}
```

I want the object c to be like this:

```
{"prop":1, prop1: ["ac","bd"]}
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
c.prop = a;
for (var index = 0 ; index < b.length; index++){
    c.prop1[index] = b[index] + b1[index];
}
```

Comment: do you mean just `c.prop = a; c.prop1 = b`?

Comment: I just edited the question. I want to do processing. So I want to add element one by one.  Not directly like c.prop1 = b

Comment: What's the value of `c.prop1` before your `for` loop? If `c.prop1` isn't defined yet, you can't set properties on it with `c.prop1[index] = ...`, and you'll see errors in your JavaScript console to that effect.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I got the answer from your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the property `prop1` in your object as an empty array `[]` and then add the proper objects to it using `push` method. The code:

```
var a = 1;
var b = ["a","b"]
var b1 = ["c","d"]
var c = {}
c.prop = a;
c.prop1 = []; // initialization
for (var index = 0 ; index < b.length; index++){
    c.prop1.push(b[index] + b1[index]); // pushing computed values
}
```

Comment: Answers with an explanation (more than just code) that explain why or what was changed are generally better than answers that are just code.  You could improve this answer by explaining.

Answer (score 1):

I think  you need to define your array `prop1` first, before you can start adding values to it;

```
c.prop = a;
c.prop1 = [];       // declare prop1 to be an empty array
for (var index = 0 ; index < b.length; index++){
    c.prop1[index] = b[index] + b1[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var associativeArray = {};
associativeArray["one"] = [];
associativeArray["two"] = [];
associativeArray["three"] = [];
```

If you are coming from OO Language then you should have a look at [this](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm)

Comment: Thanks for that link Ancient.